# XSLT: make a child node a sibling of the context node

Tags: xml, xslt

did a search for this and didn't find an answer, so here goes...

I have some xml similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<footnote ref="1">
    <para>Here is some text about some guy who made
        <emphasis role="italic">fascinating</emphasis> comment I want to quote
        <blockquote> So I went to this place and met this guy....</blockquote>
        It seemed more interesting at the time.
    </para>
</footnote>
```

I want to use xslt to change it to a new schema (using new namespace prefix)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nns:footnote ref="1">
    <nns:fn-para>Here is some text about some guy who made
        <nns:emph type="it">fascinating</nns:emph> comment I want to quote:
    </nns:fn-para>
    <nns:fn-blockquote>
        <nns:bq-para>So I went to this place and met this guy....</nns:bq-para>
    </nns:fn-blockquote>
    <nns:fn-para> It seemed more interesting at the time.</nns:fn-para>
</nns:footnote>
```

I've tried a few things...taking a para that's a descendant of footnote and looping through the children, but that's problematic because it isn't only text nodes in the para, there are also emph tags, and I still don't know how to place a child node up the tree and over in the result tree...doe that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Small refactor and extended explanation.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:nns="nns">
    <xsl:key name="kNodeByPrecedingBlock"
             match="para/node()[not(self::blockquote)]"
             use="generate-id(
                     (..|preceding-sibling::*[self::blockquote][1])[last()]
                  )"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <nns:footnote>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </nns:footnote>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".|blockquote" mode="group"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="emphasis">
        <nns:emph>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </nns:emph>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="emphasis/@role">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,2)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="blockquote">
        <nns:fn-blockquote>
            <nns:bq-para>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </nns:bq-para>
        </nns:fn-blockquote>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para" mode="group" name="makePara">
        <xsl:variable name="vGroup"
             select="key('kNodeByPrecedingBlock',generate-id())"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vGroup">
            <nns:fn-para>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup"/>
            </nns:fn-para>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        <xsl:call-template name="makePara"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<nns:footnote ref="1" xmlns:nns="nns">
   <nns:fn-para>Here is some text about some guy who made 
      <nns:emph type="it">fascinating</nns:emph> comment I want to quote 
   </nns:fn-para>
   <nns:fn-blockquote>
      <nns:bq-para> So I went to this place and met this guy....</nns:bq-para>
   </nns:fn-blockquote>
   <nns:fn-para>         It seemed more interesting at the time. 
   </nns:fn-para>
</nns:footnote>
```

**Note**: Identity rule for overwriting (just for style, but it's a good pattern). Four direct transformation rules matching `footnote`, `emphasis`, `@role` attribute of `emphasis` and `blockquote`. Grouping key matching "inline" `para`'s children: the generate id of first preceding "block" element or `para` parent. Grouping rule for `para` applying templates to self and "block" elements in `"group"` mode. Rule matching `para` in `"group"` mode (also named `makePara`): output a paragraph if there is a group with **context node** generate id as key value. Rule matching any element in `"group"` mode (it'll be any "block" element): apply templates to self ("reset" mode) and call `makePara` named template.

Comment: thanks so much for this answer, this is working really well, although I'm embarrassed to say at this moment I don't have a 100% intuitive understanding of WHY it works...will read up on keys more and try to do some different stuff with this basic method. Thanks again!